# How to build something like the H2 console app?

Tags: java, web-applications

I've been working with H2 as an embedded database and its great. However, my question is a little off-topic.
I want to make a web application that will be contained in a single jar file. I experimented with embedded Jetty and embedded Tomcat but had difficulties achieving what I want.
I see the H2 console as a model for my application - a small footprint web application that is self contained in a single jar.

Does anyone know what technology and components are used to build the H2 console app ?

Thanks

Guy

Comment: Why do you ask here if it is off topic? Ask on programmers.stackexchange. And also rephrase your question because it will get closed in its current form.

Comment: Look in the code http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/web/WebServer.java